# LINQ - Left Join Including ThenIncluding Children not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.0.2 in an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.
I have the following entities :

NotificationReported.cs :

```
public class NotificationReported
{
    public NotificationReported();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public Guid PlantId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Response> Response { get; set; }
}
```

Photo.cs:

```
public class Photo
{
    public Photo();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int NotificationReportedId { get; set; }
    public NotificationReported NotificationReported { get; set; }
}
```

Response.cs:

```
public class Response
{
    public Response();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int NotificationReportedId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public NotificationReported NotificationReported { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do a LEFT JOIN and I want to include then children. Here's what I wrote:

```
        var tableNotifReported = _myNotifContext.NotificationReported
            .Include(nr => nr.Response)
                .ThenInclude(res => res.Question)
                    .ThenInclude(question => question.QuestionTypeRef)
            .Include(nr => nr.Photo);
```

And Here's the LINQ:

```
        var query = (from notifReported in tableNotifReported 
                     join response in _myNotifContext.Response
                        on notifReported.Id equals response.NotificationReportedId into joinResponse
                     from res in joinResponse.DefaultIfEmpty()

                     join question in _myNotifContext.Question
                        on res.QuestionId equals question.Id into joinQuestion
                     from ques in joinQuestion.DefaultIfEmpty()

                     join notifTemplate in _myNotifContext.NotificationTemplate
                        on notifReported.TemplateId equals notifTemplate.Guid
                     select new NotificationsReportedQuery
                     {
                         NotificationReported = notifReported,
                         Response = res,
                         Question = ques,
                         NotificationTemplate = notifTemplate
                     })
                     .Where(predicate)
                     .Select(nrq => nrq.NotificationReported)
                     .Distinct();
```

After calling ToListAsync(), my list of objects doesn't have his children => Response (Count = 0) and Photo (Count = 0)

But when I use the usual JOIN (Inner Join) my children are here.
What's missing ?

That's the code with INNER JOIN that's working but I need a LEFT JOIN because in this context a NotificationReported may not have a Response answered by the user, so the INNER JOIN would not report this kind of notifs:

```
        var query = (from notifReported in tableNotifReported
                     join response in _myNotifContext.Response
                        on notifReported.Id equals response.NotificationReportedId

                     join question in _myNotifContext.Question
                        on response.QuestionId equals question.Id

                     join notifTemplate in _myNotifContext.NotificationTemplate
                        on notifReported.TemplateId equals notifTemplate.Guid
                     select new NotificationsReportedQuery
                     {
                         NotificationReported = notifReported,
                         Response = response,
                         Question = question,
                         NotificationTemplate = notifTemplate
                     })
                     .Where(predicate)
                     .Select(nrq => nrq.NotificationReported)
                     .Distinct();
```

EDIT:
That's what I have with LINQ LEFT JOIN (which does'not include its children):
[image: Result with LEFT JOIN]

And that's what I have with the classic INNER JOIN (for the same notif it includes the children):
[image: Result with INNER JOIN]

Comment: Did you try using navigation properties instead of joins inside the LINQ query? Also the "non working" query is using `_myNotifContext.NotificationReported` instead of `tableNotifReported`.

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work :( BTW I edited my post because it was indeed tableNotifReported instead of _myNotifContext.NotificationReported

Comment: What EFC version are you using? I've tried with the latest official EFC 2.0.2 / SqlServer database and it seems to work.

Comment: It works ? x) I have nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.6 (which use EFC 2.0.2) I can edit my post with pictures if necessary

Comment: I updated my post with pictures showing the result about LEFT JOIN vs INNER JOIN